# Appending value using React.js

Tags: reactjs

I made todo app using jquery and now using react making same app. I made general layout of the app using react but facing problem in appending element by clicking button. The code i made in jquery was.

```
    function entervalue()
    {
      var text = $('#inputext').val();
          $("#list").append('<li class="item"> <input type="checkbox" class="option-input checkbox"> ' + text + '<button class="destroy"></button><li>');
      $("#inputext").val('');
    }
```

Here the value of input field is stored in var text. 
    List is appended in having checkbox, 'text' and a button.
        I want same code to be written in react, so that when i click on button the following list gets appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `state` to store the new value. Save it as an `array`. React does a re-render when the state changes. During that render, `map()` through the value in the state and generate the HTML out of it.

```
this.setState({ //put this inside the 'onChange' handler of <input/>
 value: e.target.value
})
```

This will set the new value to the state.

```
var todo = this.state.value.map(function(value){
 return <li class="item"> <input type="checkbox" class="option-input checkbox">{value}<button class="destroy"></button><li>
})
```

`todo` will have the latest list of user inputs.

**[UPDATE]**

Check the example https://jsfiddle.net/Pranesh456/1veb7bdg/1/

Comment: m new to react can u please guide me?

Comment: I used ref to store the value of input field in a variable and tested it with alert  , its working correct. now that i have stored the value in variable i want to append that variable into <ul> defined in function

Comment: @GauravSoni added example! Check!

Comment: @GauravSoni Consider upvoting the answer

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is fundamentally different than React... you need to think of how you store data in `state`.. not actual `DOM` elements (jQuery like). You'll want to define your DOM elements in your `render` method and have it iterate through your `state` to generate the elements.

I made this repo to help teach a developer the transition from jQuery to React.. it might be helpful to checkout: https://github.com/bradbumbalough/react-tunes.

**I also highly reccomend** this doc if you're new to React: [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html).